# How to add color to the edge of a switch

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I'm using flutter's Widget Switch (), I want to add color to the border but I can't.
Can somebody help me.
I am new to using flutter.[image]

[image]

Update the post.
I want to add color to the border of that switch

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?µ

[image]

You can achieve this by placing your `Switch` inside a `Container` with a `border`:

### Full source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final checked = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                color: checked.value ? Colors.green : Colors.red, width: 2.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          ),
          child: Switch(
              value: checked.value,
              onChanged: (_) => checked.value = !checked.value),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Update the post.I want to add color to the border of that switch

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean. And the image you added is too small (22x12 pixels) to add any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the border of the `Switch` button based on the default button of Flutter. However, there is a popular package names [flutter_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_switch/example) that you can use to create a `Switch` button with customize border color. You can use it as:

```dart
FlutterSwitch(
    value: isSwitchOn,
    activeSwitchBorder: Border.all(color: Colors.green),
    inactiveSwitchBorder: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
    activeColor: Colors.yellow,
    onToggle: (value) {
        setState(() {
           isSwitchOn = value;
        });
    },
)
```